# Clean out our [container]

Tags: discussion, status-planned, retag-request, tags, tag-cleanup-request

The [container](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/container) tag appears to be too broadly scoped to be useful in its current state. With its oldest question being from 2010, it is used for many different areas of expertise including but not limited to:

- Docker Containers
- Truecrypt containers
- Video encoding stuff (H.264, SWF, Quicktime, FFMPEG)
- Virtual Machines (VMs)

Are there more tightly-scoped tags that should be used instead?

Comment: Probably the Docker, Truecrypt, HyperV, VMWare, and various encoding tags are all better.